# Is there an MSBuild task that will write lines to the *start* of a file?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm using a WriteLinesToFile to update a change log file (txt). It appends the text to the end of the file. Ideally, I'd like to be able to write the changes to the **start** of this file.

Is there a simple task (e.g. in the Community or Extension packs) that does this?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491914/how-can-i-insert-lines-into-a-file-in-an-msbuild-task/21500030#21500030 which also has a good answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't seen something like that in the custom task pack.

You could cheat by using `ReadLinesFromFile` and `WriteLinesToFile` :

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LogFile>log.txt</LogFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Log Include="Line1"/>
  <Log Include="Line2"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="WriteFromStart">
  <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(LogFile)" Condition="Exists('$(LogFile)')">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Log"/>
  </ReadLinesFromFile>

  <WriteLinesToFile File="$(LogFile)" 
                    Lines="@(Log)" 
                    Condition="@(Log) != '' And (@(Log) != '\r\n' Or @(Log) != '\n')"
                    Overwrite="true">
  </WriteLinesToFile>
</Target>
```

Or you could create a custom task.

Comment: Is there any way to stop it stripping the blank lines (between log entries)?

Comment: Add a condition to WriteLinesToFile  --> 
Condition="@(Log) != '' And (@(Log) != '\r\n' Or @(Log) != '\n')"

Comment: I bit the bullet yesterday and wrote a custom task, but I might go back to this as I don't like maintaining stuff unless it absolutely necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @dommer: If you're doing a good bit of exotic stuff in this direction, I'd suggest considering a powershell inline task or psake